# SQL Logic - logic involving Update statement with Group By clause

Tags: sql, group-by, logic

Trying SQL after a long time.
Need you help to solve this task.
I have created a Procedure for updating a column's values from row 1 to N based on other Column combinations.
Currently, other columns are populated and the calculated column is null

Ex:

```
Account Category    Metric  Count   Calculated Cloumn 5
A          1         ABC     45             
A          1         DEF     25             
A          1         XYZ                    
B          5         ABC     29             
B          5         DEF
```

In above table Calculated Column 5 is the field in Focus that is to be calculated using combination of first 4 fields,

ex:

```
if Account=a ,Category=1 and metric -abc,def,xyz then 
    sum(count) Group by Account and Category
```

Different logics for different combination.

Now i am using below procedure script:

```
SET @variable1 = (select sum(count)
    from table1
    where [Category]  = '1'
    and [ACCOUNT] = 'A'
    and [Metric Name] =  'ABC' );

SET @variable2 = 'select sum(count)
    from table1
    where [Category]  = '1'
    and [ACCOUNT] = 'B'
    and [Metric Name] =  'DEF' ';


update [dbo].[table1]
    set calculated field = (
    (case when 
        @variable1 > '0'
    then 
        @variable1
    else
        @variable2
    end)
```

Problem with this script is that the Output value is replicated across all the rows rather than just for that combination.
Basically i need to use Group by `Account` and `Category` column for calculated field so that output values are reflected only for that combination.

Comment: What is the RDBMS ?

Comment: Perhaps <sql-server>?

Comment: Clearly not understand your problem but variable1 value is your first record it means 45 and variable2 value is 0 because their is no record like that and it will update 45 to all record because their is no conditions. So can you proper explain

Comment: @KavalPatel Your understanding is partially correct. In actual need is to have value 45 only in first 2 rows where  Account and Category are A and 1.For rest of the rows it should still mark a null. Please refer to the last para of the post i.e. need to write group by using Account and category field.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table1]
    SET calculated field = (
    (CASE WHEN 
        @variable1 > '0'
    THEN 
        @variable1
    ELSE
        @variable2
    END)
WHERE [Category]  = '1'
    AND [ACCOUNT] = 'A'
    AND [Metric Name] =  'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming SQL Server based on the syntax.

I don't think variables are the right approach.  For the information you have provided:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             sum(count) over (partition by Account, Category) as sum_1
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set calculated_field = sum_1
    where Account = 'A' and Category = 1 and metric in ('abc', 'def', 'xyz);
```